# What values must $\alpha$ be so that $F$ is an isomorphic linear transformation? (Bijective)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $F:P_2\to P_2$ where $P_2$ is a polynomial vector space with max grade of 2.
>   $$[F]_B=
>         \begin{pmatrix}
>         \alpha & -1 & -1 \\
>         -6 & \alpha +1 & 0 \\
>         0 & 0 & \alpha +3 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   $$ B= \{1-x , 1+x^2 , 3-x\}
> $$

So the question at hand be the following: What value(s) must $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ equal so that $F$ is an isomorphic (bijective) Linear Transformation?

So from what I understand of L.T., the columns of $[F]_B$ should be it's image generators. Thus the linear combination of them and the Basis should give us our transformed vectors. What I don't understand is how to check for conditions in which $\alpha$ yields a non-isomorphic L.T.
$dim(P_2)=dim(P_2)$ should be the condition for an isomorphic L.T. if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: A linear transformation is bijective if and only if it is full rank if only if only its matrix representations are invertible.  Does this help?

Comment: And to add to @Bye_World’s comment, another equivalent characterization is that the matrix have non-zero determinant; in this example that seems to be the easiest approach.

Comment: @Bye_World Those "only if's" really got me. It now makes sense, I am determined to make sure the determinant goes nowhere near zero. The property was not known to me.

Comment: @FemtoComm If you'd like to see even more equivalent properties, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem).

Comment: @Bye_World Although invertible matrix theorem is extremely useful to know, I was more curious to the origin of the property pertaining to the L.T. and how it had to be invertible, see my comment on Cameron Buie's answer

Comment: @FemtoComm Look at the item on that list "The linear transformation mapping $x$ to $Ax$ is a *bijection* from $K^n$ to $K^n$."  That's exactly what you're looking for.  So every other thing on that list is equivalent.

Comment: @Bye_World Wait, so... all invertible matrices are isomorphic maps?

Comment: @FemtoComm They are all *representations* of linear isomorphisms with respect to some basis.

Comment: @Bye_World Thank you Ed.

Comment: @FemtoComm: It's okay for the determinant to be "near zero" (whatever that means), so long as it isn't *equal* to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: What is the determinant of your matrix?

Comment: So the matrix must be invertible due to the nature of the transformation ($P_2 \to P_2$). What is the formal way of saying this or just summing up the property?

Comment: Well, are you aware that a matrix is invertible iff its determinant is non-$0$?

Comment: The analogous result for linear maps is that a linear map is invertible iff its eigenvalues are all non-zero. The determinant of a linear map is simply the product of its eigenvalues, and so....